# PHP: NULLish value checking

Tags: php, null

When checking a superglobal like `$_GET` or `$_POST` for existence of a value for a particular key, is there a method that encompasses the following functionality in a more concise way?

```
if (isset($_POST['foo']) && $_POST['foo'] !== '') {
    // ...
}
```

The `isset()` function by itself returns `TRUE` even when the value is an empty string `''`, so I can't use that.

Using just `$_POST['foo'] !== ''` will work correctly by itself, but it emits an `E_NOTICE` for undefined index, which is undesirable.

The `empty()` function returns `TRUE` for the value `"0"`, which is a valid value, so I can't use that, either.

Am I missing something obvious, or is this really the best/only way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you are looking for [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php):

```
if (array_key_exists('foo', $_POST)){
    // will execute when $_POST['foo'] is set, even if to null, false, '' etc.
};
```

If you do not want to match empty string (`''`), then your solution is probably enough. Solution above gives you `false` only when the key does not exist.

Comment: I believe this will work, since `$_POST` values can never be `NULL`, `FALSE`, etc. (right?).  I mean, barring someone overriding it, that is.

Answer (score 2):

You can always silence the `E_NOTICE`. In this case, you expect a `E_NOTICE` to be thrown if the variable isn't set (and really, it's the only possible error condition here) so it is safe to be silenced.

```
if(@$_POST['foo'] != '') {

}
```

Comment: I disagree with "_it's the only possible error condition here_". Someone could have overwritten `$_POST` variable and you may get quite a broad range of errors, including eg. fatal errors: http://ideone.com/3DkzZ. Don't use silencing operators (http://stackoverflow.com/a/11588901/548696), and if someone uses it - feel free to use [_scream_ extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.scream.php).

Comment: @Tadeck: On a comparison (ie.: **in this specific case**), no other possible error condition exists. The example you have given is not a comparison. While I agree that silencing operators should not normally be used, **this is one situation where it can be used safely**.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do the whole post in one shot using [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) at the start of the script.

i.e.

```
$default = array('foo' => "2", 'bar' => 'Hello World');
$postValues = array_merge($default, $POST);
```

Then use `$postValues`. It gets over `isset` everywhere in the rest of the code as the defaults will be used instead.

Comment: It took me a few minutes to understand how this would be applicable to my question.  Basically, I would need to define a `$default` array of nothing but `NULL` values for all possible parameters.  Then I could use the `$postValues['foo'] !== ''` method, since `foo` is guaranteed to always be set, and since `NULL !== ''`, it would accomplish what I want.

Comment: @drrchknlsn - Even better - you could put other default values in as well.