# More concise ternary expression?

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I often find myself needing to write code with the following logical pattern:

```
$foo = isset($bar) ? $bar : $baz;
```

I know about the `?:` syntax:

```
$foo = $bar ?: $baz;
```

...which, on the surface, appears to be what I'm looking for; however, it throws an undefined notice index when `$bar` is not set.  It also uses the same logic as `empty()`, meaning that "empty" values like `FALSE`, `0`, `"0"`, etc. don't pass.  Hence, it's not really equivalent.

Is there a shorter way of writing that code without throwing a notice when `$bar` is not set?

**Edit:**

To make it a bit more clear *why* I'm looking for a shortcut syntax, here's a better example:

```
$name = isset($employee->getName())
      ? $employee->getName()
      : '<unknown>';
```

In this case, `$employee` might be an object from a 3rd-party library, and it might be a valid scenario that its `name` might be `NULL`.  I'd like to set variable `$name` to the returned name (if there is one), but some sensible default if there isn't.

If the method call is more complex than just a getter, then the example becomes even more verbose, since we have to cache the result:

```
$bar = $some->reallyExpensiveOperation();
$foo = isset($bar) ? $bar : $baz;
```

Comment: Think about it: in one expression you would like to check existence avoiding the notice (`isset()` does that) and if it is set, then set to the first variable, otherwise set to the second? You have two choices: the first you have proposed and the second involving silencing the notices.

Comment: You can suppress the warnings: `$foo = @$bar ?: $baz;`... but I wouldn't do that.

Comment: @nickb: Exactly. Doing that is very bad idea. There is even an extension called "_scream_" (afair), which is targeted as disabling silencing operators (`@`).

Comment: You must have a very busy in life that you cannot fit in those few extra seconds to type is `isset` etc.

Comment: You may be saving a few characters when writing such code, but when it comes to debugging it can quickly turn into a big time-wasting nightmare. I completely discourage anyone using such cryptic code. But it's your code, do whatever you want...

Comment: @EdHeal: That argument never wins.  A ton of what's implemented in most modern programming languages is syntactic sugar and shortcuts.  Heck, the ternary operator itself is just that.

Comment: @drrcknlsn - You must be writing very code from me. All my internal variables are set (they are in my control). The only ones that I need to check if they are set are from `$POST` etc (the outside world). Then I do not even use `isset` by `array_merge` to make a copy putting in defaults if they do not exist.

Comment: @EdHeal:  You're assuming `$bar` is an internal variable.  Feel free to substitute something like `$foo = isset($bar->getQuux()) ? $bar->getQuux() : $baz`, where `$bar` is an instantiation of a class from a 3rd party library if it makes more sense to you.  I was simply breaking down the logic into the simplest possible case to get my point across.

Comment: Just to, y'know, randomly raise consciousness, **the** *conditional operator* is an example of **a** *ternary operator*.  `?:` is the conditional operator.  (I know Zend documents it as "the ternary operator".  Zend are well-known to be idiots.) See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_conditional_operator.

Comment: @chaos:  What I'm actually looking for is the equivalent of a [null coalescing operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator).

Comment: @drrcknlsn: Oh, man, wouldn't *that* be awesome.  PHP is probably too married to all this "forcing you to check `isset()` a million times all over your code if you don't want to spew warnings that are computationally expensive even when suppressed" business, though.  God I miss Perl sometimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would only use the short hand ternary syntax when you explicitly predefine your variables or use an object with a magic getter. This is a very basic example of where I would normally use short hand ternary syntax

```
class Foo {
    public function __get($name) {
        return isset($this->{$name}) ? $this->{$name} : '';
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$bar = $foo->baz ?: 'default';
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [error control operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) you could technically shorten it to:

```
$foo = @$bar ?: $baz;
```

If `$bar` isn't set, the value evaluates to null, and you get no error notice since you suppressed the error.  Some, however, might not approve of this code since its not nice to use `@` since it masks errors and makes debugging more difficult.

Without that, no I don't believe there is a shorter notation that just using `isset`.

Edit:  As noted by @drrcknlsn, this won't work if the variables are `false`, or `0`, or even `null`, so it would seem to me that there is no avoiding the calling of `isset`.

Comment: Pssh -1, valid answer to the question.  OP asked for a shorter expression and that is shorter.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I also can't upvote, as I really would hate to see something like this in production code.

Comment: I +1'ed to offset it.  Some people don't understand SO rating. :-P

Comment: I would not do what you proposed and I am against your answer, but I will not downvote it exactly for that reason: it is just a valid answer to this question.

Comment: @nickb I saw your comment with the same answer pop up just as I was finishing typing up my answer.  I agree, I wouldn't use it, but threw it out there as well as a technical answer to the question.

Comment: I don't understand why using `@` in this case would be considered bad.  _In this particular case_, it's not masking potential future bugs.  It's covering up for the fact that we know there's a possibility of `$bar` not existing, but we're too lazy to use the longer `isset()` expression.

Comment: @drrcknlsn Agreed, but I might argue that counteracting another's ostensibly undeserved vote is not the proper use of SO's voting system either.

Comment: @drrcknlsn I'd only advise against it because it makes it potentially more work in debugging to tell if the value is just `null`/`false`/`0` or not set in general so you then have to stop and figure out for which of those reasons its evaluating to false.

Comment: In any case, this was a good question since it sparked such lively debate and commentary.

Comment: @drew010: Understandable, though I think the nature of the expression itself means we don't care what the actual value is.  That said, I forgot that `0`, `FALSE`, etc. wouldn't pass, so I can't use this method anyway.

Comment: @drrcknlsn Good call, I didn't really think of that point when answering so it seems there isn't really a great replacement for isset to shorten it.

Comment: @drrcknlsn: If you have to suppress an error, you should have written your code differently (sorry to be blunt, this is a universal truth). The conciseness of your code is **unimportant** if it is at the expense of being robust.

Comment: Isn't the error suppressor also extremely expensive in terms of performance?

Answer (score 0):

When `$bar` is not defined, there isn't really a "shorter" way to write the same code.

There are two, what I would consider "hacks" to do it, however, they also may impact other things:

1. Error throttling with `@`, such as `$foo = @$bar ?: $baz;` will
   do exactly what you want and throttle the undefined-error that is
   thrown when `$bar` is undefined. If it is defined, it will also work
   as desired. The downside is, however, that `@` can reduce efficiency
   in your code if it's used repeatedly.
2. Turning off notices with
   `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);`. This will still display all
   regular errors but just not the notices, which will effectively hide
   the "variable is undefined" error. The downside to this is that you
   will not see any other notices.

Now, my obligatory personal opinion, I would suggest to continue writing it out full-hand. The ternary operator is already shorthand, effectively reducing the following:

```
if (isset($bar)) {
    $foo = $bar;
} else {
    $foo = $baz;
}
```

into a much shorter

```
$foo = isset($bar) ? $bar : $baz;
```

and it really doesn't take much more effort to write the full ternary versus the shorter-ternary (unless your variable names are ridiculously long, of course). Also, there are going to be more than a few instances where compound ternary operations (i.e. - several ternaries in one) that will cause the extra-shorthand to be unusable; so the short-savings is not programmatically/morally satisfying (in my own opinion).

**UPDATE:** To support your edit where you're assigning `$bar` to the return-value of a function and then `$foo` based off of it - you can combine the statements into a single-line like:

```
$foo = (($bar = $some->reallyExpensiveOperation()) != null) ? $bar : $baz;
```

This is almost the same code-length as the two lines, but it can be shortened slightly from here as well. For instance, if `null` isn't the only value that you consider "not valid", but `false` also counts, you can drop the `!= null` portion entirely and allow the condition to be treated as a simple boolean value:

```
$foo = ($bar = $some->reallExpensiveOperation()) ? $bar : $baz;
```

In this example, `$bar` is still accessible after the ternary operation (i.e. - it doesn't lose scope), so unless you need to do pre-processing on the variable there isn't a big downside to this method, other than readability.